# My First Program Wont Cooperate

Tags: javascript

So after a short time on CodeAcademy I am trying to write my first program and want it to ask a user if they are ready then when they are, flip a coin 1,000 times and record the results. After one question here I thought I had some kinks worked out and changed from a 'while' loop to a 'for' loop. This worked and made the code much more simple but wouldn't work if the user selected 'No' when asked the first time if they were ready. To fix that I tried to add a second 'For' loop and now my program wont run at all and there is an error on line 16 where I introduce an 'Else' statement. What did I do wrong here? Also any suggestions on an easier way for the user to have a chance to change their answer to 'Yes' on the second (or repeated) prompting and still run the original loop? Thank you.

```
var userReady = prompt("Are you ready for a simulation of 1,000 coin flips?! So probability. Much randomness.");

var heads = 0;

var tails = 0;

if (userReady.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if (coinFace === 0) {
            heads++;
        } else {
            tails++;
        }
    }
} else {
    confirm("Oh come on, live a little!");
    var comeOn = prompt("Are you ready now?");
    if (comeOn.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
        for (j = 0; j <= 1000; j++) {
            var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            if (coinFace === 0) {
                heads++;
            } else {
                tails++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        confirm("Where is your sense of adventure?");

    }


    confirm("I came up heads " + heads + " times!");
    confirm("I came up tails " + tails + " times!");
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, you might be interested in Code Review SE. Great place to get suggestions on your code as you improve and learn.

Answer (score 4):

Missing last `}` for the most outer ELSE block.

It will be

```
} else {
    // the rest of code
    confirm("I came up heads " + heads + " times!");
    confirm("I came up tails " + tails + " times!");
}
```